# How to get MAX rownumber with rowNumber in same query

Tags: sql, netezza

I have `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) rnum` in a sql statement to give me row numbers. is there a way to attach the max rnum to the same dataset going out?

what I want is the `row_number()`  which I get, but I also want the MAXIMUM rownumber of the total return on each record.

```
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) rnum,
    C.ID, C.FIELD1, C."NAME", C.FIELD2, C.FIELD3
    FROM SCHEMA.TABLE 
    WHERE (C.IS_CRNT = 1)
), MAX_NUM as (
    SELECT DATA.ID, max(rnum) as maxrnum from DATA GROUP BY DATA.COMPONENT_ID
) select maxrnum, DATA.* from DATA JOIN MAX_NUM on DATA.COMPONENT_ID = MAX_NUM.COMPONENT_ID
```

DESIRED RESULT (ASSUMING 15 records):

```
1     15    DATA
2     15    DATA
3     15    DATA
etc...
```

Comment: Hi Arcee. Just to clarify, are you intentionally not partitioning the row_number? If so, the max row number would simply be the count. Is that accurate?

Comment: Wanted to make sure here, are you asking to:  If you have a 100 record table it should return 100 and if you have a 25 record table it should return 25 in your second column?

Comment: exactly!.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `count(*)` as a window function:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) as rnum,
       COUNT(*) OVER () as cnt,
       C.ID, C.FIELD1, C."NAME", C.FIELD2, C.FIELD3
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE 
WHERE C.IS_CRNT = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my assumptions in your dataset, this is the approach I would take:

```
WITH CTE AS (
select C.ID, C.FIELD1, C."NAME", C.FIELD2, C.FIELD3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE WHERE (C.IS_CRNT = 1))
SELECT *, (select count(*) from cte) "count" from cte;
```

Comment: Gordon's query accomplishes the same goal, and might be more readable for you. Both work.